# How to find Size & Height for a tree?

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree

**size of tree** = number of nodes in tree

**height of tree** = the largest depth of the tree

I am implementing a tree in c++ with:
    class node
       private:
         list children;
         char* tag;
         int value;

Comment: Can you write a definition for size in plain English? "Size of a tree is ...".

Comment: You can't find node height without reference to parent. Or you should recalculate depth of Elements after new Elements added.

Answer (score 1):

If size is number of Element's children (direct and indirect) and element itself:

```
int Element::size(){
   if (children.empty())
     return 0;

   size_t size = 0;
   for (const auto &child : children)
      size += child->size();

   size += children.size();

   if (_depth == 0) return size + 1;
   else return size;
}
```

Comment: gomons: This works great. Thank you! It doesn't include the root node though.

Comment: Root node is special. I frequently create type RootElement, inherited from Element, that has its own implementation of methods.

Comment: It's not that special

Comment: You can define size() as number of Element's children and the Element itself, so `return size;` turn to `return size + 1;`. And it includes root node too, I think.

Comment: @dingalapadum, but I change size() definition. Now node without children has size 1, and if node has children its size 1 + children sizes.

Comment: @gomons: ok. I think you are right. Deleted my comment

Comment: @gomons I just did if it is the root element return size + 1 and if not then return size.

Comment: @Jbirdwell, I accept your changes, but they are very strange from my point of view (=