# Calculating Binary search tree height

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree

what is the right way of calculating the height of a BST?

- the depth of the tree + 1?
- the number of edges?
- other?

Comment: "The height of a tree is the length of the path from the root to the deepest node in the tree. A (rooted) tree with only a node (the root) has a height of zero." - Wikipedia
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2597754/4181011

Comment: You could define height in slightly different ways. It shouldn't really matter though.

Comment: @SimonKraemer - This is an arbitrary definition. If OP stumbles upon an implementation using a different one, this can be misleading.

Comment: @BennyK The definition is not arbitrary at all. The height of a binary tree is `the number of edges on the longest path` or `the number of nodes on the longest path -1` or `the depth of the tree -1` --> which are all the same.

Comment: @BennyK I would be surprised if you can find a different definition, but please proof me wrong. Honestly, I would be interested to see if I misinterpreted something.

Comment: @SimonKraemer If I were to implement a tree structure, I could just as easily decide that the height is the number of rows, which means that a tree with a single (root) node is of height 1. The **choice** to address this question in terms of path length **is** arbitrary.

Comment: There must be a better forum out there for non programming basic questions like this

Comment: @BennyK For me that's like saying "If I define a new container it is up to me to define the size to not include the first element". You could do that but you would deviate from the majority of definitions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find Size & Height for a tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29591015/how-to-find-size-height-for-a-tree)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the definition for the height of a tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209777/what-is-the-definition-for-the-height-of-a-tree)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Confused - Height of Binary tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449845/confused-height-of-binary-tree)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between tree depth and height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603692/what-is-the-difference-between-tree-depth-and-height)